# How do I log into AWS without my MFA device?

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-factor-authentication

I need to change my payment method on my AWS account.

So I need to log into AWS. But it prompts me for the number on my MFA device. I don't recall setting up an MFA device for that, but I might have. I have at least 4 authenticator apps on my phone for various accounts. None seems to be for Amazon. I might have changed phones since I set it up, but I don't think so.

In order to get any support from AWS, you must sign in. If you can't sign in, you have to sign in to get assistance signing in.

They don't have a support phone number.
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/aws-phone-support
If it were my password I'd forgotten, I'd be in luck.
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/forgot-aws-sign-in-credentials

I'm supposed to be able to "sign in using other factors" and do an email address verification.
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/reset-root-user-mfa

But, of course, the page offers no email address verification. The "alternative factor" to email, password, and MFA is ... email, password, and MFA.

How on earth do I regain access?!?!?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to contact AWS support https://support.aws.amazon.com/#/contacts/aws-account-support/

Comment: If your MFA device is lost, damaged, or not working, you can sign in using alternative factors of authentication. There is the "Troubleshoot MFA" link under the MFA input field.

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for Programming Q&A. You are likely to receive a better response at: https://repost.aws/